# How to make system ui (status bar/navigation bar) never disappear/always present?

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I want top and bottom system ui components like status bar and navigation bar never hide and always be visible in all screens.
How to implement that?

I don't understand default behavior.

I have played with `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode()` parameters, but have not reached desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To make the system status bar & navigation bar visible.

```
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```

To make the system status bar & navigation bar invisible.

```
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import "package:flutter/services.dart";
```

Comment: Tried it. This solution is close, but still I find that bars goes away sometimes, for example, when I switch screens.

Comment: It depends on where you're using it & how you're using it.

Comment: In main function. Is it correct?  After using `Navigator.pop(context)` on the screen app goes to the previous screen and hides bottom navi bar.  And after that clicking on the screen shows bar again.